# Create a ragged/jagged 3d array in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, ragged

I want to create a ragged 3d array as followes in java.

**Terminology**: A 2D array is said to consist of rows and columns. A 3D array is said to consist of slabs, where each slab consists of a 2D array.

The first slab has three rows, the second slab five rows, and the third slab seven rows (i.e., if s denotes the slab, the number of rows in the sth slab is 3+2*s). Within the sth slab, the jth row should have s+j+1 columns

My approach was,

```
int[][][] mat3d = new int[3][][];
mat3d[0] = new int[3][];
mat3d[0] = new int[5][];
```

But this gives a compile error. Can anyone please help me to do this. I'm in a real hurry.

Comment: You'll get answers faster if you actually tell us the error, rather than making us guess.  By the way, it compiles fine when I type it, assuming it's inside a method.

Comment: @DavidWallace Thanks for pointing me in the correct direction. My hurry has pushed me to write this outside a method which is actually silly. Thanks again.

Comment: @DavidWallace Any idea what should I do to this question? Delete or Edit?

Comment: You should post your solution to it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Error was not due to the code fragment in the question.
Compilation failed as the code was not written inside a method.
Writing the code with in a method fixes the problem.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int[][][] mat3d = new int[3][][];
    mat3d[0] = new int[3][];
    mat3d[0] = new int[5][];
}
```

This compiles fine.

Comment: Until I realized you had answered your own question, I was like "Why the hell would someone answer something that the poster is obviously not that ignorant to not do". Heh. Good to see people solving their own issues :).